# OpenCV: Problems with Stereo Rectification (using sample code from book)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, stereo-3d

So I am having problems with OpenCV. I used the sample code from the book, "Learning OpenCV". I got the code to compute all of the intrinsics and extrinsics of the two cameras, but when I go to Remap the images, all I get is a blank image. I use 6 images from both cameras, with a 9x6 chessboard. The input file alternates with left and right images (the lr=i%2 made me think that...).

Below is my code. I only added the cvRemap() function towards the end.

```c
#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG

#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\cxmisc.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

//
// Given a list of chessboard images, the number of corners (nx, ny)
// on the chessboards, and a flag: useCalibrated for calibrated (0) or
// uncalibrated (1: use cvStereoCalibrate(), 2: compute fundamental
// matrix separately) stereo. Calibrate the cameras and display the
// rectified results along with the computed disparity images.
//
static void
StereoCalib(const char* imageList, int useUncalibrated)
{
    IplImage* L_img1 = cvLoadImage("bad1.bmp");
    IplImage* R_img1 = cvLoadImage("good1.bmp");
    IplImage* fixed_L = cvCloneImage(L_img1);
    IplImage* fixed_R = cvCloneImage(R_img1);

    CvRect roi1, roi2;
    int nx = 0, ny = 0;
    int displayCorners = 1;
    int showUndistorted = 1;
    bool isVerticalStereo = false; //OpenCV can handle left-right
                                   //or up-down camera arrangements
    const int maxScale = 1;
    const float squareSize = 1.f;  //Set this to your actual square size
    FILE* f = fopen(imageList, "rt");
    int i, j, lr, nframes = 0, n, N = 0;
    vector<string> imageNames[2];
    vector<CvPoint3D32f> objectPoints;
    vector<CvPoint2D32f> points[2];
    vector<CvPoint2D32f> temp_points[2];
    vector<int> npoints;
    //vector<uchar> active[2];
    int is_found[2] = {0, 0};
    vector<CvPoint2D32f> temp;
    CvSize imageSize = {0,0};

    // ARRAY AND VECTOR STORAGE:
    double M1[3][3], M2[3][3], D1[5], D2[5];
    double R[3][3], T[3], E[3][3], F[3][3];
    double Q[4][4];

    CvMat _M1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, M1 );
    CvMat _M2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, M2 );
    CvMat _D1 = cvMat(1, 5, CV_64F, D1 );
    CvMat _D2 = cvMat(1, 5, CV_64F, D2 );
    CvMat _R = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R );
    CvMat _T = cvMat(3, 1, CV_64F, T );
    CvMat _E = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, E );
    CvMat _F = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, F );

    CvMat _Q = cvMat(4, 4, CV_64FC1, Q);

    char buf[1024];

    if( displayCorners )
    cvNamedWindow( "corners", 1 );

    // READ IN THE LIST OF CHESSBOARDS:
    if( !f )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not open file %s\n", imageList );
        Sleep(2000);
        return;
    }

    if( !fgets(buf, sizeof(buf)-3, f) || sscanf(buf, "%d%d", &nx, &ny) != 2 )
    return;
    n = nx*ny;
    temp.resize(n);
    temp_points[0].resize(n);
    temp_points[1].resize(n);

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        int count = 0, result=0;
        lr = i % 2;
        vector<CvPoint2D32f>& pts = temp_points[lr];//points[lr];

        if( !fgets( buf, sizeof(buf)-3, f ))
            break;

        size_t len = strlen(buf);
        while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]))
        buf[--len] = '\0';

        if( buf[0] == '#')
            continue;

        IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( buf, 0 );

        if( !img )
            break;

        imageSize = cvGetSize(img);
        imageNames[lr].push_back(buf);

        //FIND CHESSBOARDS AND CORNERS THEREIN:
        for( int s = 1; s <= maxScale; s++ )
        {
            IplImage* timg = img;

            if( s > 1 )
            {
                timg = cvCreateImage(
                    cvSize(img->width*s,img->height*s),
                    img->depth, img->nChannels
                );
                cvResize( img, timg, CV_INTER_CUBIC );
            }

            result = cvFindChessboardCorners(
                timg, cvSize(nx, ny),
                &temp[0], &count,
                CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH |
                CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
            );

            if( timg != img )
                cvReleaseImage( &timg );

            if( result || s == maxScale )
                for( j = 0; j < count; j++ )
                {
                    temp[j].x /= s;
                    temp[j].y /= s;
                }

            if( result )
                break;
        }

        if( displayCorners )
        {
            printf("%s\n", buf);

            IplImage* cimg = cvCreateImage( imageSize, 8, 3 );
            cvCvtColor( img, cimg, CV_GRAY2BGR );

            cvDrawChessboardCorners(
                cimg, cvSize(nx, ny), &temp[0],
                count, result
            );

            IplImage* cimg1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
            cvResize(cimg, cimg1);
            cvShowImage( "corners", cimg1 );
            cvReleaseImage( &cimg );
            cvReleaseImage( &cimg1 );

            int c = cvWaitKey(1000);
            if( c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q' ) //Allow ESC to quit
                exit(-1);
        }
        else
            putchar('.');

        //N = pts.size();
        //pts.resize(N + n, cvPoint2D32f(0,0));
        //active[lr].push_back((uchar)result);
        is_found[lr] = result > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        //assert( result != 0 );

        if( result )
        {
            //Calibration will suffer without subpixel interpolation
            cvFindCornerSubPix(
                img, &temp[0], count,
                cvSize(11, 11), cvSize(-1,-1),
                cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 30, 0.01)
            );

            copy( temp.begin(), temp.end(), pts.begin() );
        }

        cvReleaseImage( &img );

        if(lr)
        {
            if(is_found[0] == 1 && is_found[1] == 1)
            {
                assert(temp_points[0].size() == temp_points[1].size());
                int current_size = points[0].size();

                points[0].resize(current_size + temp_points[0].size(), cvPoint2D32f(0.0, 0.0));
                points[1].resize(current_size + temp_points[1].size(), cvPoint2D32f(0.0, 0.0));

                copy(temp_points[0].begin(), temp_points[0].end(), points[0].begin() + current_size);
                copy(temp_points[1].begin(), temp_points[1].end(), points[1].begin() + current_size);

                nframes++;

                printf("Pair successfully detected...\n");
            }

            is_found[0] = 0;
            is_found[1] = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");

    // HARVEST CHESSBOARD 3D OBJECT POINT LIST:
    objectPoints.resize(nframes*n);

    for( i = 0; i < ny; i++ )
        for( j = 0; j < nx; j++ )
            objectPoints[i*nx + j] = cvPoint3D32f(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0);

    for( i = 1; i < nframes; i++ )
        copy(
            objectPoints.begin(), objectPoints.begin() + n,
            objectPoints.begin() + i*n
        );

    npoints.resize(nframes,n);
    N = nframes*n;

    CvMat _objectPoints = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &objectPoints[0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0] );
    CvMat _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0] );
    CvMat _npoints = cvMat(1, npoints.size(), CV_32S, &npoints[0] );

    cvSetIdentity(&_M1);
    cvSetIdentity(&_M2);

    cvZero(&_D1);
    cvZero(&_D2);

    // CALIBRATE THE STEREO CAMERAS
    printf("Running stereo calibration ...");
    fflush(stdout);
    cvStereoCalibrate(
        &_objectPoints, &_imagePoints1,
        &_imagePoints2, &_npoints,
        &_M1, &_D1, &_M2, &_D2,
        imageSize, &_R, &_T, &_E, &_F,
        cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
        CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
        CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
        CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH +
        CV_CALIB_FIX_K3
    );
    printf(" done\n");

    // CALIBRATION QUALITY CHECK
    // because the output fundamental matrix implicitly
    // includes all the output information,
    // we can check the quality of calibration using the
    // epipolar geometry constraint: m2^t*F*m1=0
    vector<CvPoint3D32f> lines[2];

    points[0].resize(N);
    points[1].resize(N);

    _imagePoints1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[0][0] );
    _imagePoints2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC2, &points[1][0] );

    lines[0].resize(N);
    lines[1].resize(N);

    CvMat _L1 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &lines[0][0]);
    CvMat _L2 = cvMat(1, N, CV_32FC3, &lines[1][0]);

    //Always work in undistorted space
    cvUndistortPoints(
        &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints1,
        &_M1, &_D1, 0, &_M1
    );
    cvUndistortPoints(
        &_imagePoints2, &_imagePoints2,
        &_M2, &_D2, 0, &_M2
    );

    cvComputeCorrespondEpilines( &_imagePoints1, 1, &_F, &_L1 );
    cvComputeCorrespondEpilines( &_imagePoints2, 2, &_F, &_L2 );

    double avgErr = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        double err =
            fabs(
                points[0][i].x*lines[1][i].x +
                points[0][i].y*lines[1][i].y + lines[1][i].z
            ) +
            fabs(
                points[1][i].x*lines[0][i].x +
                points[1][i].y*lines[0][i].y + lines[0][i].z
            );
        avgErr += err;
    }
    printf( "avg err = %g\n", avgErr/(nframes*n) );

    // save intrinsic parameters
    CvFileStorage* fstorage = cvOpenFileStorage("intrinsics.yml", NULL, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
    cvWrite(fstorage, "M1", &_M1);
    cvWrite(fstorage, "D1", &_D1);
    cvWrite(fstorage, "M2", &_M2);
    cvWrite(fstorage, "D2", &_D2);
    cvReleaseFileStorage(&fstorage);

    //COMPUTE AND DISPLAY RECTIFICATION
    if( showUndistorted )
    {
        CvMat* mx1 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* my1 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* mx2 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_32F );
        CvMat* my2 = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_32F );

        CvMat* img1r = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_8U );
        CvMat* img2r = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_8U );

        CvMat* disp = cvCreateMat( imageSize.height, imageSize.width, CV_16S );

        double R1[3][3], R2[3][3], P1[3][4], P2[3][4];
        CvMat _R1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R1);
        CvMat _R2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, R2);

        // IF BY CALIBRATED (BOUGUET'S METHOD)
        if( useUncalibrated == 0 )
        {
            CvMat _P1 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P1);
            CvMat _P2 = cvMat(3, 4, CV_64F, P2);

            cvStereoRectify(
                &_M1, &_M2, &_D1, &_D2, imageSize,
                &_R, &_T,
                &_R1, &_R2, &_P1, &_P2, &_Q,
                CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY,
                1, imageSize, &roi1, &roi2
            );

            CvFileStorage* file = cvOpenFileStorage("extrinsics.yml", NULL, CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
            cvWrite(file, "R", &_R);
            cvWrite(file, "T", &_T);    
            cvWrite(file, "R1", &_R1);
            cvWrite(file, "R2", &_R2);
            cvWrite(file, "P1", &_P1);    
            cvWrite(file, "P2", &_P2);    
            cvWrite(file, "Q", &_Q);
            cvReleaseFileStorage(&file);

            isVerticalStereo = fabs(P2[1][3]) > fabs(P2[0][3]);
            if(!isVerticalStereo)
                roi2.x += imageSize.width;
            else
                roi2.y += imageSize.height;

            //Precompute maps for cvRemap()
            cvNamedWindow( "Original" );
            cvNamedWindow( "Fixed" );

            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M1,&_D1,&_R1,&_P1,mx1,my1);
            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M2,&_D2,&_R2,&_P2,mx2,my2);
            cvRemap(R_img1, fixed_R, mx2, my2);
            cvShowImage("Original", R_img1);
            cvShowImage("Fixed", fixed_R);
            while(1){
                int c = cvWaitKey(15);
                if(c == 'p') {
                    c = 0;
                    while(c != 'p' && c != 27) {
                        c = cvWaitKey(250);
                    }
                }
                if(c == 27)
                break;
            }// end while

        }

        //OR ELSE HARTLEY'S METHOD
        else if( useUncalibrated == 1 || useUncalibrated == 2 )
            // use intrinsic parameters of each camera, but
            // compute the rectification transformation directly
            // from the fundamental matrix
        {
            double H1[3][3], H2[3][3], iM[3][3];

            CvMat _H1 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, H1);
            CvMat _H2 = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, H2);
            CvMat _iM = cvMat(3, 3, CV_64F, iM);

            //Just to show you could have independently used F
            if( useUncalibrated == 2 )
                cvFindFundamentalMat(&_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints2, &_F);

            cvStereoRectifyUncalibrated(
                &_imagePoints1, &_imagePoints2, &_F,
                imageSize,
                &_H1, &_H2, 3
            );

            cvInvert(&_M1, &_iM);
            cvMatMul(&_H1, &_M1, &_R1);
            cvMatMul(&_iM, &_R1, &_R1);

            cvInvert(&_M2, &_iM);
            cvMatMul(&_H2, &_M2, &_R2);
            cvMatMul(&_iM, &_R2, &_R2);

            //Precompute map for cvRemap()
            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M1,&_D1,&_R1,&_M1,mx1,my1);
            cvInitUndistortRectifyMap(&_M2,&_D1,&_R2,&_M2,mx2,my2);
        }
        else
            assert(0);

        cvReleaseMat( &mx1 );
        cvReleaseMat( &my1 );
        cvReleaseMat( &mx2 );
        cvReleaseMat( &my2 );
        cvReleaseMat( &img1r );
        cvReleaseMat( &img2r );
        cvReleaseMat( &disp );
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    StereoCalib(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stereo_calib.txt", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Below are the extrinsic matrices obtained from the program.

```
    R: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 3
       dt: d
       data: [ 9.9997887582765532e-001, 4.2746998112201760e-003,
   -4.8964109286960510e-003, -4.1317666335754111e-003,
   9.9957553950354616e-001, 2.8838677686057253e-002,
   5.0176092857428471e-003, -2.8817837665560161e-002,
   9.9957208635962669e-001 ]
    T: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 1
       dt: d
       data: [ -8.3141294302865210e-001, -3.2181226087457654e-001,
   -4.5924165239318537e-001 ]
    R1: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 3
       dt: d
       data: [ 8.3000228682826938e-001, 3.1110786082949388e-001,
   4.6293423160308594e-001, -3.1818678207964091e-001,
   9.4578880995670123e-001, -6.5120647036789381e-002,
   -4.5809756119155060e-001, -9.3249267508025396e-002,
   8.8399728423766677e-001 ]
    R2: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 3
       dt: d
       data: [ 8.2904793019998391e-001, 3.2089684317297251e-001,
   4.5793530708249980e-001, -3.1381823995200708e-001,
   9.4482404014772625e-001, -9.3944906367255512e-002,
   -4.6281491084940990e-001, -6.5823621903907531e-002,
   8.8400769741835628e-001 ]
    P1: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 4
       dt: d
       data: [ -4.4953673002726404e+001, 0., -1.3375267505645752e+001, 0.,
   0., -4.4953673002726404e+001, 2.4430860614776611e+002, 0., 0., 0.,
   1., 0. ]
    P2: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 4
       dt: d
       data: [ -4.4953673002726404e+001, 0., -1.3375267505645752e+001,
   4.5081911684079330e+001, 0., -4.4953673002726404e+001,
   2.4430860614776611e+002, 0., 0., 0., 1., 0. ]
```

And the intrinsic parameters found are as follows.

```
    M1: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 3
       dt: d
       data: [ 4.3107336978610317e+002, 0., 3.4686501809547735e+002, 0.,
   4.3107336978610317e+002, 1.9221944996848421e+002, 0., 0., 1. ]
    D1: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 1
       cols: 5
       dt: d
       data: [ -1.6825480517169825e-001, 1.0756945282000266e-001, 0., 0., 0. ]
    M2: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 3
       cols: 3
       dt: d
       data: [ 4.3107336978610317e+002, 0., 3.5310162800332756e+002, 0.,
           4.3107336978610317e+002, 1.8963116073129768e+002, 0., 0., 1. ]
    D2: !!opencv-matrix
       rows: 1
       cols: 5
       dt: d
       data: [ -1.9546177300030809e-001, 1.7624631189915094e-001, 0., 0., 0. ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am not very experienced with OpenCV, and I have a hard time wrapping my head around what most of the functions are even doing. So I ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer. After much experimenting, it seemed that the flag for cvStereoCalibrate, CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH, caused my output images to appear warped and/or not work. Also, I took many more chessboard pictures with a larger chessboard, and this seemed to help my results quite a bit.

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Also for anyone in the future: if you actually use two identical cameras, leave this flag in and look for the error elsewhere. You will reduce the precision of your calibration otherwise.